# Scroll not working when editable={false} on TextInput. Android Only

Tags: react-native

I have a selection of react-native `TextInput` components with `editable={false}` at the start of a form.

On Android I'm unable to scroll on the disabled TextInputs, meaning the user can't scroll down to the other content.

I have tested on a selection Android and iOS devices. It seems to be only Android having the issue.

```
<Input
placeholder="Address"
disabled={true}
editable={false}
returnKeyType="next"
/>
```

The user should be able to scroll on the TextInput as they can in iOS.